# Is there a way to dynamically update "month" value in custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not sure if I phrased the question right. What I need is for a certain custom function in this case "ImportJSON()" to be able to import the present month into it's arguments in order for it to display the value correspondent to the present month without me having to manually update/write the month name every beginning of the month. Did that make sense?

Here is a dummy file as example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

So as you can see when I reference a cell where I wrote down "August" the custom function accepts it. But if I reference a cell which uses "now()" it displays an error:

```
"This function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(), RAND() or RANDBETWEEN()"
```

From what I understood Google changed something in Apps script in that it makes it not possible to do this?

Is there a workaround? A way to make the custom function import the present month as argument automatically in such a way I don't have to update it every month?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM")
```